# How does a server power supply withstand unto toggling the power?

Tags: electrical-power, power-supply-unit

My server will run only weekly for 2 hours for backup purposes. After I finished the backuping I pull out the power plug from the power outlet. 
How does a server power supply withstand unto toggling the power? Will it fail shortly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running for two hours every week means one start and one per week. Any power supply should be able to handle that.

But I would suggest that you use a power strip that has a switch on it, and use the switch. Actually plugging the plug could wear the plug and/or the socket on the long run.

Comment: I wonder more what type of server that supposedly is that only runs 2 hours per week.

Comment: @TomTom -> I guess it's the server in this [question](http://serverfault.com/questions/334270/servers-power-supply-always-on-even-if-it-is-turned-off)

Comment: Not really. 2 hours per week for a backup would more ask for an external hard disc.

Comment: @TomTom -> Yes, but let's assume there is a reason for that...

Comment: I thought a pc, server or nas with a raid system is more secure than a simple external hdd.