# Dell PowerEdge 850 PSU FAN always on

Tags: hardware, dell, dell-poweredge

I have a Dell PE 850 wich is used unfrequently. I've noticed that the PSU fan is always running as soon as I plug the power cord in.
So I have several questions regarding this behaviour:

1.) Is it normal/common?

2.) If yes - for what reason?

3.) Is there a known way to stop the fan from spinning all the time if the server is powered off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a couple servers that do the same thing. Most servers have an integrated management chip that is powered by the PSU, so the fans will stay running.

Here's a related question with further explanation: [Server's power supply always on even if it is turned off](https://serverfault.com/questions/334270/servers-power-supply-always-on-even-if-it-is-turned-off)

Comment: The system has a management chip to provide IPMI over LAN access. I've disabled that one to be sure. I'm a bit confused why this behaviour is necessary because I have a Poweredge 1950 with a DRAC enterprise card which should be much more power hungry and there is no fan spinning all the time... nevertheless: maybe you're right

Comment: The other thread mentioned the user disabled the management function but the fan still spun. It's basically hard-wired so even if disabled the board would still draw power.

Comment: okay, so I'm going to live with that - but still hate it :-D